# Launch WSL from Windows Terminal with different environment variables

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wish to setup different Windows Terminal launch configurations so that I can use `bash` on WSL in different windows, each with a different environment profile which is configured from the command line - not by adding a new script each time.

Setting up one `WSL` is easy, I create a Windows Terminal profile  which runs bash with my standard `.profile` with command:

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04
```

However my PC has different Linux JDKs, and I wish have Windows Terminal launchers "JDK18", "JDK19" and "JDK20" each to open WSL `bash` with different profile per JDK.

Currently I can achieve the above using Windows Terminal profile with the command `bash.cmd NN`, and `bash.cmd` is this script:

```
@echo off
rem Runs bash with no PATH from Windows
set Path=

:: Optional arguments are JDKVER:
if x%1 NEQ "" (
   set JDKVER=%1
   set WSLENV=%WSLENV%::JDKVER
)
rem WSLENV is a list of env variables that are passed from Windows to WSL
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl
```

Because my `.profile` contains these lines, the correct JDK NN environment variables are setup in the resulting `bash`:

```
[[ -z $JDKVER ]] && export JDKVER=20
export JAVAHOME=/mnt/c/linux/jdk-$JDKVER
```

Is there a way to define the Windows Terminal launcher which bypasses my use of Windows `CMD`? Example using something which could configure WSL launch with a different environment setting for each profile in needed in Windows Terminal:

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 -envvar JDKVER=xxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments to this [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1762286/windows-terminal-run-a-command-when-starting-wsl-and-keeping-the-shell-open) led me to a way to set a WSL/bash environment variable without running CMD as script or scriptlet. This is the Windows Terminal command:

```
wsl -e bash --noprofile -c "export JDKVER=18 && exec bash --rcfile ~/.profile"
```

The resulting `bash` shell picks up the environment variable `JDKVER=18` and the profile is loaded incorporating the change. Note that it has side effect of running `bash` twice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by using additional
Windows Terminal profiles.

To
[call Windows Terminal with a profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments)
use :

```
WindowsTerminal.exe -p profile-name
```

The command-line of the profile can be similar to :

```
cmd.exe /k "set JDKVER=foo&& set WSLENV=%WSLENV%::JDKVER&& wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04"
```

Comment: Thanks this works though note that the command-line of the profile mustn't have spaces after foo or the variable JDKVER ends with the space too, change to `...set JDKVER=foo&&...`

Comment: Changed as suggested.